# Consulta en Access con un ciclo While

Tags: sql, ms-access

Buenas.
Tengo un problema, quisiera seleccionar datos de mi base de datos en `Access` con un rango de fechas y un nombre en especifico. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Mi pensamiento es con un `While` pero no me funciona.

```
select * from Registro
While Fecha_uso between #12/19/2016# and #12/23/2016# 
where name = 'Juan'
```

Answer (score 4):

While no es un comando SQL.

Tu pensamiento esta perfecto, pero lo que escribiste en el while debe ir en el where.

```
select * from Registro
Where Fecha_uso between #12/19/2016# and #12/23/2016# 
and name = 'Juan'
```

Comment: En Sql si se puede hacer un while?

Comment: no. while no es un comando de sql. Sql por defecto ya recorre todos los registros.

Answer (score -1):

comandos basicos de mysql son:

> select: selecciona los valores de los campos que quieres obtener
>
> from:
>   mencionar las tablas de los atributos
>
> where: detalla las condiciones
>   para que tu consulta sea efectiva

en tu caso esta mal el while, si embargo es where, tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
Where Fecha_uso between #12/19/2016# and #12/23/2016#
```